# How to Filter a search with an objects properties efficiently in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, array-filter

Hey guys i've searched for hours and still cant find a proper way to search though my data base. I have an array of contact objects that have a username and name property and I have a "add user" view controller where the **GOAL** is to loop through all the users in my data base , and when searching , it widdles down the users in a UITABLEVIEW this is what I have so far.

**Cliff notes of code below**:

I get all my user objects from my database and store them in an array of type [contact] called "results" (custom object) then i attempt to filter the results and store those into a new array called "filteredData" Contact has type "userName" (String) which I would like to filter results by

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
class SearchForUsersViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var results = [Contact]()
var filteredData = [Contact]()
var isSearching = false;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    searchBar.delegate = self;

    searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    getUserList()
}

@IBAction func dismiss(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func getUserList(){
    //populates results
    staticValuesForData.instance.dataBaseUserref.observe( .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let userList = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]{
            for user in userList{
                 let name = (user.childSnapshot(forPath: staticValuesForData.instance.fName).value as! String) + " "
                    + (user.childSnapshot(forPath: staticValuesForData.instance.lname).value as! String)

                let contact = Contact(name: name , uid: user.key,
                                      pic: user.childSnapshot(forPath: staticValuesForData.instance.profileUrl).value as! String,
                                      userName: user.childSnapshot(forPath: staticValuesForData.instance.userName).value as! String )
                print(contact.name)
                print("user" , user)

                self.results.append(contact)

            }

        }
    }

}
```

}

table view extension :

```
extension SearchForUsersViewController : UITableViewDataSource , 
UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if isSearching{
        return results.count

    }
    return 0;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell" , for: indexPath) as! AddedMeTableViewCell;
    cell.profilePicture.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: filteredData[indexPath.item].picUrl)
    if isSearching{
    cell.userName.text = filteredData[indexPath.item].userName!
    }
    else
    {
          cell.userName.text = results[indexPath.item].userName!
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 80;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```

}

Search extension (where the **issue** is )

```
extension SearchForUsersViewController : UISearchBarDelegate{

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text == "" || searchBar.text == nil{
        view.endEditing(true)
        isSearching = false;
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    else{
        isSearching = true
        ifSearchContains(word: searchBar.text!)
        tableView.reloadData()
        print(filteredData)
        print(results)
        print(searchBar.text)
    }
}

func ifSearchContains(word : String)
{
    for result in results{
        if result.name.contains(word){
            filteredData.append(result)
        }else{

        }
    }
}
```

}

I have the search function above but it is not filtering , nor is the idea of it very efficient. this application is going to have thousands of users, can you please help me filter a search in an efficient way? Thank you so much

Here is the contact custom object just in case

```
import Foundation

class Contact : NSObject , Comparable{

let name : String!
let uid : String!
let picUrl : String!
let userName : String!
init(name : String , uid : String , pic : String , userName : String) {
    self.name = name
    self.uid = uid
    self.picUrl = pic
    self.userName = userName
}

static func ==(lhs: Contact, rhs: Contact) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name
}

static func <(lhs: Contact, rhs: Contact) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name < rhs.name
}
```

}

Comment: why don't you just use .filter? something like filteredData = results.filter { $0.name.contains(word)  }

Comment: First get rid of all those implicitly unwrapped optionals in your Contact class properties

Comment: @koropok I guess ill have too, i was hoping to find a more efficient way but this works for now thanks for checking out my post :)